# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest - Gather specified data

Tags: powershell, network-printers

I am trying to collect `Total Pages Printed` from a printer's web page. The script can...

1. Load the login page.
2. Navigate to the maintenance sub-page
3. Select the column with the desired data

However, I don't know how to adjust the script to only capture the numbers I need.

```
$R=Invoke-WebRequest http://1.2.3.4/status.html -SessionVariable session1

#B553 - name w Html
$R.Forms[0].Fields["B553"]="login"
$R.Forms[0].Fields["password"]="password"

$Invoke1=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("http://1.2.3.4/status.html" + $R.Forms[0].Action) -WebSession $session1 -Method POST -Body $R.Forms[0].Fields

Start-Sleep -s 5

$Invoke2=Invoke-WebRequest 'http://1.2.3.4/Maintance-sub-page' -WebSession $session1

$Invoke2.AllElements | where tagname -EQ "dd" | Select innerText
```

The result of the following:

```
$Invoke2.AllElements | where tagname -EQ "dd" | Select innerText
```

- is on the screen. But the output I am looking for should be like "*Total Pages Printed 23513*"

[Total Pages in web-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7id0j.jpg)

[Total pages result in PS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUYz8.jpg)

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Veq56.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the results in Powershell are in the same order as those on the HTML page. It looks kind of like those results are an array, and (if I counted right), it looks like the field you want is 23 (the array starts at 0).

Give the following a try...

```
$($Invoke2.AllElements | where tagname -EQ "dd" | Select innerText)[23]
```

Comment: Thank You Adam!
After casting variable again it returns the result i was lookig for :)
innerText 
--------- 
23527pages

Comment: @Bah Fantastic. Would you mind marking this answer as successful by clicking the check mark beside it. This way other folks that come across this thread know this resolved your issue.